# Segmentation Fault occurs when unit testing with GMock with boost pointers

Tags: c++, unit-testing, pointers, boost, googlemock

I'm having trouble adding a unit test for a class that I have. One of the functions uses a boost pointer (dynamic pool) and there's always a segmentation fault that occurs whenever I compile the test as seen from the backtrace. If run normally, it compiles properly but when using Google Mock it fails.

The Mock::AllowLeak also does not seem to work for me. Unfortunately, I cannot share the code in public so if anybody has experienced testing functions that uses boost pointers with Google Mock feel free to share some tips.

Thank you

---

Function to be tested:

```
RetObj* Foo::FooFunction(uint32_t param1)
{
  spRetObj_t ptr = pool_storage->Get<RetObj>(); //error occurs when I use this
  ...
  return ptr;
}
```

spRetObj_t initialize:

```
typedef stdex::IPool<RetObj>::iptr spRetObj_t;
```

Pool storage:

```
#include "stdex/dynamic_pool.hpp"
...
class PoolStorage
{
...
    template<typename T>
        typename stdex::IPool<T>::iptr Get(void (T::*on_free)(void) = 0);
...
}
```

Code in boost where the exception was thrown:

```
T * operator->() const
{
    BOOST_ASSERT( px != 0 );
    return px;
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample code. We can't consult the crystal ball to see what you've done wrong. :)

Comment: @ezaquarii I've added a few snippets. Let me know if I need to add anything else.

Comment: Provided code is not enough to give the clear answer, [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be nice. I can only tell for sure that you are trying to dereference `NULL` `boost:shared_ptr` (or whenever that exception occurs, `boost::optional` is similar). Is your `pool_storage` a shared_ptr and can be `NULL`?